# Apache JMeter сохранение результата запроса в файл. Как указать имя файла

Tags: testng, jmeter

Добрый день. Настроил тест таким образом, что из полученной в запросе страницы регулярным выражением получается участок кода с названием файла, которое я помещаю в переменную ***DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME***, также получаю ссылку на скачивание и следующим запросом скачиваю файл, который сохраняется на диск при помощи ***Save Responses to a file***, но при этом формируется имя либо инкрементом, либо датой и временем.  Каким образом задать имя файла в листанере ***Save Responses to a file***? Есть возможность указать параметр ***Filename prefix*** я задал такое ***D:\test\${DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME}***, однако, переменные в этом месте не парсятся.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте property, например:

```
D:\test\${__P(DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME,)}
```

Property можно задать как минимум двумя способами:

1. В файле *user.properties* (живет в папке "bin" в корне JMeter)

   ```
   DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME=foo.txt
   ```
2. Через аргумент командной строки -J

   ```
   jmeter -JDOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME=foo.txt -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

Больше информации:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

---

Альтернативный вариант: [JSR223 Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor). Вы можете записать ответ в файл при помощи кода на языке [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/):

```
new File('D:/test/' + vars.get('DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME')) << prev.getResponseDataAsString()
```

Comment: У меня названия файлов можно получить распарсив страницу, я не могу заранее знать какие у них будут имена.

Comment: Альтернативный вариант: [JSR223 Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor). Вы можете записать ответ в файл при помощи кода на языке [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black): `new File('D:/test/' + vars.get('DOWNLOAD_FILE_NAME')) << prev.getResponseDataAsString()`.

Comment: Да , это то что надо. Оформите ответ я галочку поставлю